# Print string if present in two separate columns

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have a text file with two columns and I want to print only the strings that are present in both of them. For example:

```
column1       column2

stringA       stringZ
stringP       stringT
stringZ       stringX
stringE       stringR
stringT       stringG
```

Expected output:

```
stringZ
stringT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shamelessly stolen from @cherdt with some improvement (assumes a shell like `zsh` or `bash` with support for `ksh`-like process substitution):

```
f=filename; comm -12 <(cut -f1 < "$f" |sort) <(cut -f2 < "$f" | sort)
```

- Keeping filename in variable helps not repeat it
- No need to write to files, then to compare. Writing to files usually requires to delete them afterwards for cleanup. Don't do this with huge files though. Process substitution makes it look like `comm` is reading from files whereas it's `stdout` redirection to a temporary `fd`

Answer (score 2):

With different awk solution and easy

```
awk 'NR==FNR{seencol1[$1]++;next} ($2 in seencol1)' infile.txt infile.txt
```

output,

```
stringZ
stringT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `comm` to compare 2 files, so first generate a sorted file for each column:

1. `cat filename | cut -f1 | sort > column1`
2. `cat filename | cut -f2 | sort > column2`

Then suppress the first 2 columns of `comm` to display only the rows where the data exists in both files:

`comm -12 col1 col2`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NF!=1{cola[$1]++; colb[$2]++} END { for (item in cola ) { if( colb[item]>0 ) { print item } }' /path/to/input
```